# Change the LAZY fetch type of an entity for a query to EAGER

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multiple-choice

How to change the LAZY fetch type of an entity for a query to EAGER?
A)Using @EntityGraph
B)Using @NamedEntityGraph
C)Both A & B
D)Not Possible

Comment: where is the code and what have you tried?

Comment: It's a multiple choice question. I can understand stackoverflow may not be the right platform to ask mcq. Do you suggest any other forum where I can ask spring related mcq.